# Only execute the next function if all items in list are checked

Tags: python

I am a little stumped in this code that I have written (Pardon me if my title is misleading..).
See the following code:

```
my_dict = {'aaa' : 12, 'bbb' :34, 'ccc' : 56}
my_inputs = ['aaa', 'bbb']

def check(user_input):
    input_check = my_dict.get(user_input)
    if not input_check:
        raise ValueError('{0} is not part of the dictionary'.format(user_input))
        #sys.exit()
    #return 
    return input_check

for i in my_inputs:
    check(i)
    print 'Executing next...'
```

In an ideal scenario, assuming if the contents within `my_inputs` are all correct and find-able in my_dict, it is executing in the way that I wanted.

However, if I change the contents to `my_inputs = ['aaa1', 'bbb']`, going by this order, it is unable to print out the statement in the for loop.
But if I change it to `my_inputs = ['aaa', 'bbb1']`, it will first prints out the statement then raise the ValueError. Though this is right as `aaa` does exists in the dictionary.

My question here is - I am trying to make my `check` function to check all the inputs at one go and see if it exists within the dictionary before execution the next function. Whether the order of `my_inputs` are `['aaa1', 'bbb']` or `['aaa', 'bbb1']`, it should simply stop at the ValueError and does not prints out the statement. The statement will only be print if all items in my_inputs are accounted for in my_dict.

I tried using `sys.exit()` and `return`, but that does not seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the logic of raising exception outside of check.

```
my_dict = {'aaa' : 12, 'bbb' :34, 'ccc' : 56}
my_inputs = ['aaa', 'bbb']

def check(user_input):
    input_check = my_dict.get(user_input)
    return input_check is not None

failed_result = [key for key in my_inputs if not check(key)]
if not failed_result:
    print("It's OK!")
else:
    print("The following key(s) is(are) not in dict!", failed_result)
```

Or make check simpler, `[key for key in my_inputs if key is not in my_dict]`

Answer (score 0):

To see is a variant of any of the elements that exists in `my_inputs` also exists in the dictionary, you can try this:

```
my_inputs = ['aaa1', 'bbb']
my_dict = {'aaa' : 12, 'bbb' :34, 'ccc' : 56}
final_vals = [i for i in my_inputs if any(i.startswith(c) or c.startswith(i) for c in my_dict)]
```

Output:

```
['aaa1', 'bbb']
```